# "checksum bad" error loading rom with hack Snes9x

Tags: mods, snes, super-metroid

I have been using the Snes9x emulator to run Super Metroid for some years now. Today, I discovered hacks and have been experimenting with Hyper Metroid, for example. I have downloaded Lunar IPS to apply the hacks to the roms.

While I got Hyper Metroid to work, I am having trouble getting the infamous Justin Bailey hack to work. Every time I try to run it I get some yellow text saying "`checksum bad`", and a jumbled up Nintendo logo in the middle. Nothing else happens, unless I load a saved state. Even though I can still play the game, Samus leaves something to be desired.

Anyone know how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: This is how the game tests the files to see if they are what they are supposed to be - this hack must tamper with the game files and it is sensing it and not allowing you to continue until the checksum matches

Comment: @Penguin good to know. Although I fixed the problem with a preloaded rom :P